# Why consider velocity from our own reference frame in Einstein's Addition

Tags: special-relativity, velocity

I'm trying to understand Einstein's Velocities Addition concept in Special Relativity. I know how to derive the equation from Lorentz Transformations, but I'm trying to take an intuitive (or at least physical) feel for it.

As you can see in [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/einvel.html) website (image below), $u$ is the projectile velocity as seen from A, and $u'$ is the projectile velocity as seen from B. Looking at $u'$: since we are at B reference frame, why are we subtracting $V$ to get the projectile velocity? I mean, if we are at B, shouldn't our velocity in our own reference frame be $0$?

[image]

Comment: Because that's the way the question is asked. It's an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @JohnDoty but if I'm B, why is $V$ taken into account? $V$ should be my velocity from A, so I don't understand why it is considered (because my velocity relative to myself is 0). On the other hand, A is going backward with velocity $-V$, but it shouldn't be important to the velocity of the projectile according to me (B)

Comment: Because in the problem, you're not B, you're A. If you're B, it's a different problem.

Comment: @JohnDoty oh, I think I see it. So $u'$ is actually "the velocity as seen by B if I am A". Is it right? I do not change from one frame of reference to another, I'm always A. That's what I think I'm messing up in understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be good to first consider a more familiar analogue,
as well as adopt a more useful systematic notation.

Drawn in A's xy-plane,

[image: robphy-anglesslopes]

- Composition-of-angles (which is additive).
  $\theta_{PA}=\theta_{P\underline{B}}+\theta_{\underline{B}A}$. (Note the indices.)
- Composition-of-slopes, where $m=\tan\theta$.
  \begin{align}
  \tan\theta_{PA}
  &=\tan(\theta_{P\underline{B}}+\theta_{\underline{B}A})\\
  &=\frac{\tan\theta_{PB}+\tan\theta_{BA}}{1-\tan\theta_{PB}\tan\theta_{BA}}\\
  m_{PA}
  &=
  \frac{m_{PB}+m_{BA}}{1-m_{PB}m_{BA}}
  \end{align}
- Relative-angles (which is subtractive).
  $\theta_{PB}=\theta_{P\underline{A}}-\theta_{B\underline{A}}$. (Note the indices.)
- Relative-slopes.
  \begin{align}
  \tan\theta_{PB}
  &=\tan(\theta_{P\underline{A}}-\theta_{B\underline{A}})\\
  &=\frac{\tan\theta_{PA}-\tan\theta_{BA}}{1+\tan\theta_{PA}\tan\theta_{BA}}\\
  m_{PB}
  &=
  \frac{m_{PA}-m_{BA}}{1+m_{PA}m_{BA}}
  \end{align}

---

Now for velocities in special relativity.

Drawn in A's position-vs-time graph [spacetime diagram] (with $t$ running horizontally, like the usual position-vs-time graphs in PHY 101)

[image: robphy-rapidities-velocities]

- Composition-of-rapidities (which is additive).
  $\theta_{PA}=\theta_{P\underline{B}}+\theta_{\underline{B}A}$. (Note the indices.)
- Composition-of-velocities, where $v=\tanh\theta$.
  \begin{align}
  \tanh\theta_{PA}
  &=\tanh(\theta_{P\underline{B}}+\theta_{\underline{B}A})\\
  &=\frac{\tanh\theta_{PB}+\tanh\theta_{BA}}{1+\tanh\theta_{PB}\tanh\theta_{BA}}\\
  v_{PA}
  &=
  \frac{v_{PB}+v_{BA}}{1+v_{PB}v_{BA}}
  \\
  u
  &=
  \frac{u'+v}{1+u'v}\quad\mbox{equivalent to your $u$-formula}
  \end{align}
- Relative-angles (which is subtractive).
  $\theta_{PB}=\theta_{P\underline{A}}-\theta_{B\underline{A}}$. (Note the indices.)
- Relative-velocities.
  \begin{align}
  \tanh\theta_{PB}
  &=\tanh(\theta_{P\underline{A}}-\theta_{B\underline{A}})\\
  &=\frac{\tanh\theta_{PA}-\tanh\theta_{BA}}{1-\tanh\theta_{PA}\tanh\theta_{BA}}\\
  v_{PB}
  &=
  \frac{v_{PA}-v_{BA}}{1-v_{PA}v_{BA}}\\
  u'&=
  \frac{u-v}{1-uv}
  \end{align}

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

$B$'s velocity in $B$ is zero. $A$ sees the projectile moving at $u$, and $v$ is parallel to $u$, so to get $u'$, you need to subtract $v$. The transformation on the r.h.s is from $A\rightarrow B$.

BTW: why have unprimed and primed variables, but not primed and unprimed frame namaes?